# Why do I need a tsconfig.json in each subdirectory, even if it only extends the root?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, monorepo, tsconfig

I'm trying to trim down the config files within my frontend mono repo, using Vite with react and Typescript. In the root of my repo, I've defined a `tsconfig.json` file that includes all necessary settings to run each project (including react-specific settings such as "jsx": "react-js").

The weird thing is, in any of my projects themselves if I omit a `tsconfig.json` file it throws:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

If I do include a `tsconfig.json` file, *even if the only thing it does is extend the root*, it resolves the issue.

```
{ 
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json" 
}
```

From what I understand, each subdirectory/project should reference the root config file by default.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the `include` field in the `tsconfig.json` which is in the root, the default value of this is `["src"]`, which means the files not in the `src` will not be parsed.

But I think using `extends` to separate the base config from the project config is a good practice, which allows each project to have its own config.